# Textview singleline push relative layout off the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Im trying to organize a custom cell for a listview. The listvew has a BaseAdapter to add the datas (no problem here)

my problem is when the layout comes around... here is a sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mng_dir_cell"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <!-- IMAGE -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_icone"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_border"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_tarif_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- CENTER -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_titre_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_categorie_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_promo_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- RIGHT -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annuaire_distance_etablissement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_img"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/clr_default_complement2"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_img"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icone_fleche" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i cant get the layout "center" to have a fix/propotionel size between the two others.

ex : when the title is too long the layout right goes off the screen, same goes with the categories. when there are too manies the right goes off.

I already tried Relative layout with ToRight and ToLeft but the problem is the center need to be ToRight of the left layout and ToLeft off the right layout  but not centered... if you know what i mean :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify static width for left and right elements; or use [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight), for instance:

```
<LinearLayout [...] >
    <LinearLayout [...] 
          android:layout_width="70dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout [...] 
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout [...] 
          android:layout_width="10dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: icant specify static size, the app must be ok with most of screen width. And what ll happen if i give layout_weight to only one of the layout ? wont the other be overlaped ?

Comment: Then you can set `layout_width` of all your views to `"0dp"`, and use different values for `layout_weight`, depending on the relative width you want them to be